# SFTP scripting unable to change directories question

Tags: sftp, expect

I'm relatively new to using sftp in scripting format (bash shell on Mac OSX High Sierra). I am having issues changing dirs once logged into the remote server. I want to cd to 'FTP PDF (Download) to CR'
Here is my script(edited):

```
#!/bin/bash
expect -c "
spawn sftp ClaimReturn@8.19.132.155
expect \"Password\"
send \"xxxxxxx\r\"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"cd CR\ Reports\r\"  
#DIR TO CD to "CR REPORTS"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"bye\r\"
expect \"#\"
"
```

Comment: perhaps my script commands are not too clear:

Comment: script command to cd to remote 'CR Reports' dir:        expect \"sftp>\"
send \"cd CR\ Reports\r\"

Comment: expect \"sftp>\"
send \"cd CR\ Reports\r\"

Comment: expect \"sftp>\" <br/>    send \"cd CR\ Reports\r\"  <br/>

Comment: expect \"sftp>\"

Comment: send \"cd CR\ Reports\r\"

Comment: at this point if anyone knows how to change directories on the remote site or point me to some info I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm confused because when I issue the send \"ls -lart * *\r\" command I do not get the levels that I know are there

Comment: You should use single quotes on remote names that have spaces in them, instead of backslash, for example: `send \"cd 'CR Reports'\r\" ` because the backslashes are being removed by the shell since you are inside a double-quote string. But since your shell script contains only expect commands, why not convert it to an expect script.

Answer (score 1):

This is really just an formatted comment expanding on @meuh's comment.

You're having quoting trouble. You could use single quotes or a quoted heredoc to make your life easier

```
#!/bin/bash
expect <<'END_EXPECT'
spawn sftp ClaimReturn@8.19.132.155
expect "Password"
send "xxxxxxx\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd 'CR Reports'\r"  
#DIR TO CD to "CR REPORTS"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
expect "#"
END_EXPECT
```

Or, just an expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn sftp ClaimReturn@8.19.132.155
expect "Password"
send "xxxxxxx\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd 'CR Reports'\r"  
#DIR TO CD to "CR REPORTS"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
expect "#"
```

Comment: thanks...that Windows standard of naming directories with spaces has always given me problems...I write software that can/should run on any platform/OS so I always use "_" instead of " "...but that's me (an old Motorola process-oriented dev)

Comment: another DUOH I was doing was executing the sftp command in a .sh shell instead of .sftp